# Java Spring Boot "release is not in the system" Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a project with spring initialzr and used the java 21 version. But I get this error when I run vscode without doing anything on it, how can I solve it.

The project was not built due to "release 20 is not found in the system". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent

I tried to create new project and ı got this error again and again. I am waiting to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error basically suggest that you don't have the right version of the **JDK** installed or you might be using a JRE (Java Runtime Environment which comes normally bundeled by default). If that's the case you should get the proper JDK (Java Development Kit) and update your runtime environment in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

For me the jre change to correct one(one I specified in https://start.spring.io/) in window->preferences->Java->InstalledJREs resolved the problem. It is not enough that you have installed the correct JRE/JDK- you have to use correct one in the Eclipse.